# Powershell: Write to a single Logfile

Tags: powershell, logging

I have written a small function that writes into a single logfile for each server this module is installed, but somehow a few cycles to write the line are lost, sometime I get the error file already in use. I have tested this function on different version of Powershell, PS5.1, PS6, PS7.1 x86 and x64 all with the same result.

```
        if (!(Test-Path -ErrorAction Stop -Path (Join-path -Path $ScriptLogPath -ChildPath "$FQDN.log"))) {
        New-Item -Path $ScriptLogPath -Name "$FQDN.log" -Force -ItemType File -ErrorAction Stop
    }

    $CreatedNew = $false
    $Global:MTX = New-Object -TypeName System.Threading.Mutex($true, 'Global\LogFileMutex', [ref]$CreatedNew)

    try {   
        if (-not $CreatedNew) {
            $Global:MTX.WaitOne(10000) | Out-Null
        }
    }
    catch [System.Threading.AbandonedMutexException] {
        if (!(Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\LogWriter')) {
            New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source LogWriter
        }
        Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "LogWriter" -EntryType Error -Message $_.Exception -EventId 1000
    }           
    
    ($Date + $InstanceId + $Severity + $ScriptLineNumber + $ScriptName + $Message) | Out-File -Append -FilePath (Join-path -Path $ScriptLogPath -ChildPath "$FQDN.log")
}
catch {
    if (!(Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\LogWriter')) {
        New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source LogWriter
    }
    Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "LogWriter" -EntryType Error -Message $_.Exception -EventId 1000
}
finally {
    if ($Null -ne $Global:MTX) {
        [void]$Global:MTX.ReleaseMutex()
        [void]$Global:MTX.Dispose()
    }
}
```

That is the block of code that will append the formatted string into the file.

So fare I have tried different approaches to handle the Mutex, made them globally and not. Used different approaches to append the string to the file, like Add-Content.

To try out the function I use this little script, it should write 150 lines, but end up with about 130 and no single error.

```
for ($num1 = 1 ; $num1 -le 5 ; $num1++) {
Start-Job {
    for ($num = 1 ; $num -le 10 ; $num++) {
        Write-Log  -Severity 'INFO' -Message "Starting Job $num"
        Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
            try {
                Start-Sleep -Milliseconds (Get-Random -Maximum 10)
                Write-Log  -Severity 'INFO' -Message "Starting"
                Start-Sleep -Milliseconds (Get-Random -Maximum 10)
                Write-Log  -Severity 'INFO' -Message "DONE"
            }
            catch {
                New-Item -Path "C:\Users\User\Desktop" -Name (Get-Date -Format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") -ItemType File
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every server is writing to the same logfile, i dont think that you can override "error file already in use"

Iam thinking that maby you should think over the concept and run from a server where you are monitoring by invoke-commmand ?

Comment: No each server is creating his own file to write his logs and outputs.